# for loop and iterator variable's scope

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

I am adding some new features in a long script where many variables are minified (just one letter).

When adding a for loop I had to check a lot if that traditional `i` variable, used for iteration, was available. ie not taken/defined before in this scope of the script.

My first idea was to scope it like this:

```
(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        console.log(i);    // logs 1 to 19
    }
})()
console.log('After is: ' + typeof i); // After is: undefined
```

Is there a better way to do this? what other ways can one think about in this situation?

Comment: Why are you trying to edit the minified version?  You should be editing the non-minified version.  Your *real* code should use meaningful variable names.

Comment: How long are your functions that you need to introduce IIFE in the middle just to scope an `i` variable? Why not just break it up into separate named functions?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I agree with you. The script is the way it is and I do (unfortunatly) have to work with it as it is. But I do add proper/clear variables to the parts I am adding and comment when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the script to not use one-letter variables.  But baring that, use a function instead:

```
function repeat(fun, times) {
    // Since JavaScript is function scoped
    // `i` will not leak out of the `repeat`
    // function.  We will not be able to access
    // `i` from a higher scope in this function,
    // but, we can assume that is unnecessary.
    for (var i = 0; i <= times; i++) {
        fun(i);
    }
}

var i = "some value";
repeat(function(index) {
    console.log("Index is:", index);
    console.log("`i` remains:", i);
}, 10);
console.log("After call, `i` is:", i);
```

Comment: +1 This is the best way to solve this versus using an IIFE :-)

Comment: +1 - Interesting solution to pass a function as a function parameter! Why is that better than a IIFE?

Comment: @Rikard: It's reusable!  You don't need to write `(function(){}())` everywhere.

Comment: @Rikard - so that we can easily find and replace all of these calls later, when we have fixed the script :-)